# Set different font sizes for different lines in a text box

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am attempting to create a text box that will allow different sizes of text on different lines. The text will be written through vba. I have attempted to use rich text tags to accomplish this. However, the tags I looked up online have no effect. I know there is a way to do this with VB.NET, but I can't seen to find a proper method in vba. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set the `TextFormat` property of the `TextBox` to `Rich Text`, then all the text you assign to the textbox will be interpreted as HTML (a subset of it really).

[image: TextFormat setting]

The following code:

```
 myTextbox = "<font size=1>Line 1:Small text</font><br/>" & _
             "<font size=4>Line 2:Large text</font>"
```

Will look like this:

[image: example of rich text]